# How can I migrate a table with data in a table which got a new datetime column which is non-nullable?

Tags: alembic, flask-migrate

I've added a column

```
registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
```

to my `users` table. The migration which was automatically created is

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    ...
    op.add_column('users', sa.Column('registered_on', sa.DateTime(), nullable=False))
    ...
```

When I execute it, I got an exception about an invalid value `0000-00-00 00:00:00` (or so).

How should I adjust the migration script to not have this problem?

(In this situation, filling in a dummy value would probably have been the best)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Add a `server_default` to the `add_column` operation:

```py
op.add_column('users', sa.Column('registered_on', sa.DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=func.now()))
```

2. First insert the column as nullable, then edit all your rows to have a value. Once all the rows have been given a non-null value, do another migration to alter the column to non-nullable.